# How can I merge System.Data.SQLite into a single-executable program?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to create a single-executable application in C#, which includes SQLite. System.Data.SQLite depends on one unmanaged DLL (SQLite.Interop.dll), so I can't merge it with ILMerge.

How can I bundle System.Data.SQLite into my project so I can produce a single-executable application with no tag-along DLLs?

Comment: Why you don't make a installation file for your application?

Comment: You can't. As you said, it depends on an unmanaged dll. Unmanaged dlls can't be merged into a single executable.

Comment: @Serghei Having an installer spew DLLs around the system makes it harder make your code bug-free. With one executable, if the user replaces it you know they have the latest version. No worrying whether the installer includes all the right DLLs and whether it replaced them all. Also, I think it's a better user experience to not have to go through a wizard to run my trivial application.

Comment: @Charles I've seen single-executable programs written in C and C++ before, so I figure there has to be a way to bundle in an unmanaged library, even if it's not the usual ILMerge way.

Comment: @spiffytech - but you are trying to mix managed code and unmanaged code. That is completely different than an entire app in C++ or an entire app in managed code.

Comment: @spiffytech - also, a C++ single executable program isn't really merged the same way you merge managed code - you don't merge dlls into an executable. You can merge "merge modules", but I've never seen any way to merge C++ dlls into a single assembly

Comment: Couldn't there be some way to bundle the unmanaged DLL into the .exe, unpack it in memory when the program runs, and reference it there instead of referencing it from the filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

You can include the dll as an embedded resource in the executable, then at runtime extract it (this assumes the program has permissions to write to whatever directory you are extracting the dll to).

Something like

```
string sqllitefile = "sqllite.dll";
Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (FileStream fs = fileInfoOutputFile.OpenWrite())
using (Stream resourceStream =currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(sqllitefile))
{
   const int size = 4096;
   byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
   int numBytes;
   while ((numBytes = resourceStream.Read(bytes, 0, size)) > 0) 
   {
         fs.Write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
   }
   fs.Flush();
   fs.Close();
   resourceStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to load an assembly from a memory stream. So you don't have to write it to disk.

Comment: @bitbonk - how would that work with a third-party managed assembly that needs to reference the unmanaged assembly (as the question is talking about)? If that managed assembly isn't set up to read it from memory, it wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, as soon as there is a unmanged DLLs involved this approach doesn't work.

Comment: @Chris B: How do I add a reference to my project such that System.Data.SQLite will know where to find the DLL? Do I hardcode the reference at compile time and hope I can write to that location, or is there a way to dynamically add a reference that System.Data.SQLite will see?

Comment: @spiffytech You should use DllImport, you can find more information here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/single-assembly-deployment-of-managed-and-unmanaged-code